# Is it possible to perform Action through Today Extension without opening Host App?

Tags: ios, ios8-today-widget, today-extension

I have created an host app that is fetching post from server and displaying the same.
I have also created an Today Extension and showing top most 5 under Today Section Of Notification.
Now I want to provide delete post functionality directly from Today Extension without opening Host app.
Is it possible to perform Action through Today Extension without opening Host App? And that post should also be deleted from host app.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html

Comment: I can't think of any reason it wouldn't be possible. What specific details are you concerned about?

Comment: hi..  @yadav.. u got any solution for this ?